# jQuery is not getting applied

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on notification system and loading html notification body from database to views which populate as follows:

```
<form id="acceptInviteForm" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="accountId" value="6">
    <input type="hidden" name="operation" value="acceptinvite">

    <button class="acceptinvite btn btn-primary" href="/acceptinvite" onclick="acceptingRequest();">Accept Invitation</button>
</form>
```

and applying jQuery function which I already defined on same page is like this:

```
// Accept invitation button click
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    function acceptingRequest() {

        var formData = jQuery("#acceptInviteForm").serialize();
        alert(formData);

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/acceptinvite",
            data: formData,
            dataType: "json",

            beforeSubmit: function() {
                jQuery(this).attr({"disabled":"disabled"});
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert("Success");
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("Got error while accepting invitation, reload or contact administrator!");
            }
        });
    }
});
```

So when user click on button it's not work even not showing `alert`.

*But things gets more **interesting*** when I **inject** above jquery function from chrome console while view is loaded and button start working fine and shows alert too!

I am not getting the point which not letting things work!

Comment: Remove function from `$(document).ready` and wrap it in `head`.. **[For example](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/j9hj99s5/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your **acceptingRequest function is visible only inside anonymous jQuery(document).ready callback**.

So when you click the button acceptingRequest is not visible.

### Solutions keeping jQuery(document).ready(function() {})

To solve this bind the handler inside the callback using `$('button.acceptinvite').on('click',acceptingRequest)`

or use an anonymous callback (something like this):

```
$('button.acceptinvite').on('click',function(){
    var formData = jQuery("#acceptInviteForm").serialize();
    alert(formData);
    //Etc.
});
```

In both cases remove `onclick="acceptingRequest();"` since it's no longer needed.

Another option is to make acceptingRequest visible outside using a global variable (it's not a good practice anyway):

```
acceptingRequest = function () {
    var formData = jQuery("#acceptInviteForm").serialize();
    alert(formData);
    //Etc.
}
```

Now acceptingRequest is visible outside jQuery().ready and you can do onclick="acceptingRequest();"

### Solutions without jQuery(document).ready(function() {})

If you don't need the DOM to be completely loaded (like in this case) you can remove
jQuery(document).ready(function() {}) and just write your function from in head, so they are visible to the button.

```
<script>
    function acceptingRequest() {
        var formData = jQuery("#acceptInviteForm").serialize();
        alert(formData);
        //Etc.
    }
</script>
```

Let me know if this was useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are defining the function acceptingRequest() on document ready, but you are not really calling it. Try adding:

```
acceptingRequest();
```

just after the definition of the acceptingRequest() function. The result would be:

```
// Accept invitation button click
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    function acceptingRequest() {

        var formData = jQuery("#acceptInviteForm").serialize();
        alert(formData);

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/acceptinvite",
            data: formData,
            dataType: "json",

            beforeSubmit: function() {
                jQuery(this).attr({"disabled":"disabled"});
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert("Success");
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("Got error while accepting invitation, reload or contact administrator!");
            }
        });
    }
    acceptingRequest();
});
```

Comment: Wouldnt this try and call the `acceptingRequest` function as soon as the DOM was ready. Not on user interaction which I believe is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Right, this would fire the AJAX call as soon as the DOM is ready, which I thought the OP is looking for. Otherwise, the acceptingRequest() line should be wrapped inside an event listener

Answer (score 0):

It is because this string

```
<button class="acceptinvite btn btn-primary" href="/acceptinvite" onclick="acceptingRequest();">Accept Invitation</button>
```

will be proceded by the browser earlier than the definition of your `acceptingRequest` function. 'acceptingRequest' in your code will be defined asynchronously when `document ready` fired. So browser can't assign it with the `click` listener. Try to put your script exactly before `</body>`(and after `jQuery` script) and without `jQuery(document).ready`

```
<script>
function acceptingRequest() {

    var formData = jQuery("#acceptInviteForm").serialize();
    alert(formData);

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/acceptinvite",
        data: formData,
        dataType: "json",

        beforeSubmit: function() {
            jQuery(this).attr({"disabled":"disabled"});
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert("Success");
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Got error while accepting invitation, reload or contact administrator!");
        }
    });
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Sounds good @David ! If this answer helped you, feel free to check it as right

Answer (score 0):

Function defined in ready state can be used in it's own scope.So you can use acceptingRequest() method in ready state.

in my view below code is bestpractice in event binding:

```
<form id="acceptInviteForm" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="accountId" value="6">
    <input type="hidden" name="operation" value="acceptinvite">

    <button class="acceptinvite btn btn-primary" id="acceptInviteButton" href="/acceptinvite" onclick="acceptingRequest();">Accept Invitation</button>
</form>
```

and in ready state:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
function acceptingRequest() {

    var formData = jQuery("#acceptInviteForm").serialize();
    alert(formData);

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/acceptinvite",
        data: formData,
        dataType: "json",

        beforeSubmit: function() {
            jQuery(this).attr({"disabled":"disabled"});
        },
        success: function(data) {
            alert("Success");
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("Got error while accepting invitation, reload or contact administrator!");
        }
    });
}
$("#acceptInviteButton").on("click",acceptingRequest);
});
```